# How do slimes inherit stats?

Tags: stardew-valley

When two slimes breed, the resulting baby will have a similar colour to its parents, and it feels like it has the same health as well. How exactly do parents pass their stats to the baby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The baby slime's health will be either the father's or the mother's, which is then altered by a random value between -4 and +5.

The baby's attack will be either the father's or the mother's, which is then altered by a random value between -1 and +2.

The baby's defense will be either the father's or the mother's, which is then altered by a random value between -1 and +2.

The baby's evasion will be either the father's or the mother's, which is then altered by a random value between -1% and +2%.

The baby's scale is will be either the father's or the mother's, and then altered by a random value between -2% and +3%. A slime can't be smaller than 0.6 times the average, or larger than 1.5 times the average.

As for the baby's colour, it's a little more complicated. A slime's colour is a RGB value, and the baby will take the parents' colour in one of the following ways:

- 50% of the time, the baby's colour will be a mix of the parents', in such a way: for each of the baby's colours (Red, Green, and Blue), there's a 50% chance that the colour will be the highest of the parents' colours, and a 50% chance that the colour will be an exact average of the parents' colours.
- 25% of the time, each of the baby's colours will be the mother's colours, altered by at most +/- 25%.
- 25% of the time, each of the baby's colours will be the father's colours, altered by at most +/- 25%.